# When computing arithmetic means, what way of summing is more precise?

Tags: floating-point, average, precision, mean, ieee-754

Given the task to compute the arithmetic mean of *n* IEEE 754 double precision floating point-numbers *x*<sub>0</sub>, *x*<sub>1</sub>, ..., *x*<sub>*n* - 1</sub>, is it more precise to do

> (ksum<sub>*i*</sub> *x*<sub>*i*</sub>) / *n*

(i.e. first doing a Kahan-sum of all *x*<sub>*i*</sub> and then dividing by *n*) or

> ksum<sub>*i*</sub> (*x*<sub>*i*</sub> / *n*)

(i.e. first dividing the *x*<sub>*i*</sub> by *n* and then Kahan-summing)?

My own tests (with uniformly distributed random numbers in [0, 1) and normal distributed numbers over the whole range of floating point numbers centered on 0 with σ = 1) have been inconclusive, showing that both are very precise, but my choice of test data might have been particularly poor.

Comment: I suspect that the choice will depend on what you know about your data, i.e. the likely range of the values and the typical value of `n`. For large `n` and large `x` values you may run into overflow problems with the first method. Conversely for small `x` values and sufficiently large `n` you may get denormals with the second method.

Comment: @PaulR Assuming both cases do not take place, what would be the more precise choice?

Comment: My gut feeling is the first one, since there are fewer total operations involved, but I have no evidence to back this up.

Comment: @PaulR That's what I thought, too, but the second approach turned out to be slightly more precise in my tests. This might be an artifact of how I generated input, which is why I'm asking.

Comment: I would also expect the second method to be better on average, since division is the inaccurate operation (compared to Kahan summation) and in the second method the many divisions will individually round up or down (if the distribution of xi is such that they are about as likely to round up or down when divided by n).

Comment: One thing that matters a lot is whether all xi have the same sign. If they don't it's better to first sum them as precisely as possible and then have a single division introducing an error relative to the total, instead of plenty of errors relative to the magnitudes of the summands.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sum first, then divide.  If you divide first and then sum in the general case, you introduce a rounding error proportional to the largest magnitude summand, which mostly defeats the point of Kahan summation (in the case of catastrophic cancellation, which is what you're guarding against, your result is the rounding error from the divide).

Summing first does have somewhat greater risk of undue overflow; to handle *that* correctly, you would rescale by an exact power-of-two as needed to prevent overflow.  However, this is quite rare, and never something you need to worry about with well-scaled data.

Just to provide a concrete example: consider averaging the values 4503599627370496, -4503599627370498, and 2 in double-precision.  Even using naive summation, you get the exactly correct result (0) if you sum and then divide.  If you divide and then sum, the summation is exact (by Sterbenz' lemma) and yet the error is still large; the computed result is -0.08333333333333337 (this comes only from the rounding error in 4503599627370496/3; -4503599627370498/3 is exact).